# How to create bare deflate stream from file in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, zip, gzip

So, all tools that I know put the compressed by deflate algorithm stream in some file format with headers, file names, additional check sums etc.

Is it possible to create directly a file containing only the deflate compressed stream, as described in RFC-1951, using some of standard Linux tools + bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen some development tools which can do it, but with normal tools it is not (immediately) possible, because the raw compressed stream is generally useless.

Otherwise, on Linux, `gzip --no-name` results in compressed stream with header of fixed size of 10 bytes. You can trim it with `dd`.E.g.:

```
cat something | gzip --no-name | \
  ( dd of=/dev/null bs=1 count=10; cat > gzip-without-header )
```

All what's left, is to strip the last 8 bytes (CRC, uncompressed size) from the output file:

```
dd if=gzip-without-header of=gzip-without-anything \
    bs=1 count=$[ `stat -c '%s' gzip-without-header` - 8 ]
```

P.S. GZip file format is defined in [RFC1952](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt).

Answer (score 4):

a slightly better solution (without writing to a temporary file) would be:

```
cat something | gzip --no-name | tail --bytes=+11 | head --bytes=-8 > gzip-without-anything
```

Answer (score 2):

`gzip -nc file` or `gzip < file` will produce on stdout a deflate stream with a 10-byte header and an 8-byte trailer.  You can delete the header and trailer using `dd`, though you'll need to see how big the output is in order to give the right value to `dd` to cut the end off.